# Why does the ScrollView leave a lot of unnecessary space when scrolling down?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

**My content should end on a button. That is, the button is the last bottom element.
Since there is a lot of text I had to use ScrollView. And when scrolling down, the button goes up and starts to go empty space.
I tried to set the height of the ScrollView to wrap_content. Nothing has changed.**

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.Smoke.FullscreenContainer"
    tools:context=".LectureFragment"
    android:background="@color/dark_background">
    
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="100">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:src="@drawable/day1"
                android:layout_weight="20"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_regarding_the_parent"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_regarding_the_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_between_something"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:text="@string/text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_regarding_the_parent"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_regarding_the_parent"
                android:layout_weight="10"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />

            <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                android:text="@string/submit_lecture_rus"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/height_button"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_regarding_the_parent"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_regarding_the_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_regarding_the_parent"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/coral"
                />

        </LinearLayout>

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe because of your weight sum that you've specified? You've said that all your layout weights have to add up to 100, but they don't which would probably explain the empty space.

Answer (score 0):

you probably can set the height of the Linear layout to be wrap_content

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="100">

    ...

</LinearLayout>
```